# Render as undefined, can't quite figure out the bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am wrapping up a personal project and testing for any bug, I fixed the majority bug and can't quite figure out how to resolve this one, which outputs the right counts, unit, and ingredient in the console, but seems not working when output to the webpage:

```
8 oz cream cheese, softened 
0.25 tsp garlic powder
undefined tsp dried oregano
undefined tsp dried basil
1 cup parmesan cheese
```

Before `parseIngredients` (from Web console):

```
0: "8 ounces cream cheese, softened"
1: "1/4 teaspoon garlic powder"
2: " teaspoon dried oregano"
3: " teaspoon dried parsley"
4: " teaspoon dried basil"
5: "1 cup shredded mozzarella cheese"
```

I suspect something might go wrong with the DOM manipulation, so I went back and check several times and can't find the problem.

***Recipe.js***

```
    parseIngredients(){
        const unitsLong = ['tablespoons','tablespoon','ounces','ounce','teaspoons','teaspoon','cups','pounds'];
        const unitsShort = ['tbsp','tbsp','oz','oz','tsp','tsp','cup','pound'];
        const units = [...unitsShort,'kg','g'];

        const newIngredients = this.ingredients.map( el=>{

            // uniform units 
            let ingredient = el.toLowerCase();
            unitsLong.forEach((unit,i) =>{
                ingredient = ingredient.replace(unit,unitsShort[i]);
            });

            // remove parentheses
            ingredient = ingredient.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, ' '); // regular expression


            // Parse the ingredient into count, unit and ingredient
            const arrIng = ingredient.split(' ');
            const unitIndex = arrIng.findIndex(el2 => units.includes(el2));// return true or false 


            let objIng; 
            if(unitIndex > -1){
                // there is a unit 
                const arrCount = arrIng.slice(0,unitIndex); // Ex. 4 1/2 cups, arrCount is [4,1/2] & 4 cups, arrCount is [4]

                let count; 
                if(arrCount.length === 1){
                    count = eval(arrIng[0].replace('-','+'));
                } else{
                    count =  eval(arrIng.slice(0,unitIndex).join('+'));
                }

                objIng ={
                    count, 
                    unit:arrIng[unitIndex],
                    ingredient:arrIng.slice(unitIndex +1).join(' ')
                };


            } else if(parseInt(arrIng[0],10)){
                // thre is no unit but 1st element is number 
                objIng ={
                    count:parseInt(arrIng[0],10),
                    unit:'',
                    ingredient:arrIng.slice(1).join(' ')
                }

            }else if(unitIndex === -1){
                // There is no Unit and no number at 1st element 
                objIng ={
                    count:1,
                    unit:'',
                    ingredient
                }
            }


            return objIng; 

        });

        this.ingredients = newIngredients; 
    }
}
```

Updated: Thanks for all the enthusiastic help from the community and Barmar's great catch on the problem. I did a bit digging and finds out that food2fork did not specify the amount for the ingredient. So the problem is the string will have a unit but no amount. The following are my fix but did not seem to solve the "Undefined" problem.

```
                let count; 
                if(arrCount.length === 1){
                    count = eval(arrIng[0].replace('-','+'));
                } else if(arrCount.length === undefined){
                    count = 1; 
                }
                else{
                    count =  eval(arrIng.slice(0,unitIndex).join('+'));
                }

                objIng ={
                    count, 
                    unit:arrIng[unitIndex],
                    ingredient:arrIng.slice(unitIndex +1).join(' ')
                };
```

I tried the following as well:

```
arrCount.length === 0 ;
arrCount === null;
```

Still, render undefined

I am new to web-dev and I really could use a more experienced mind and eyes to take a look at this code. And again thank you so much for all the people looking at the problem. Have a great day and happy coding !!!

Updated comments & reason for the updates:

1. This problem went from debugging to algorithm problems, may help others in the future.
2. The new question cuts considerable unrelated codes.
3. Delete rendering code, since it is later found out not the issue.

Comment: Without reading your entire codebase, it sounds like a race condition. Any chance you can simplify this question into the minimum amount of code to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: I suspect the problem is in `parseIngredients()`. Can you show the value of the ingredients string that causes these results?

Comment: There's probably something in the ingredient that's causing `eval()` to return `undefined`. Using `eval()` here is really problematic, what if there's a recipe containing `alert("foo") tsp`?

Comment: This is a great catch Barmar, I went to the API and looked up the corresponding recipe and it looks like they never defined how many teaspoons you need for the ingredient and resulting in the undefined output. @Barmar

Comment: Turns out there is a Unit but the API has no count in it @mkaatman

Comment: `arrCount.length` will never be undefined. If there's no amount before the unit, `arrCount.length == 0`.

Comment: @Barmar tried the fix, still render undefined

Comment: Can you please edit the question and show the value of `el` that's causing the problem?

Comment: I changed `if (arrCount.length == undefined)` to `if (arrCount.length == 0)`, then tried to parse `tsp flour` and it returned `{count: 1, unit: "tsp", ingredient: "flour"}`. So it's not undefined.

Comment: I suggest you extract the function inside `.map()` into a named function so you can debug it on its own.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. I have figured out the bug. Thanks for the new idea for the fix. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the fix to the problem, feel free to refer to the code in the question. 
In the Recipe.js and in the conditional statement of how we decide to parse the ingredients into counts, unit, and ingredient:

The `arrCount.length` will always be equal to 1 because for some reason the ingredients before parsing have a `''` and when reading in before the `UnitIndex`, it counts as a `count`.

Therefore the fix will be:

```
                let count; 
                if(arrCount.length == 1 && arrCount[0] == 0){
                    count = 1;
                } else if(arrCount.length == 1){
                    count = eval(arrIng[0].replace('-','+'));
                }
                else{
                    count =  eval(arrIng.slice(0,unitIndex).join('+'));
                }

                objIng ={
                    count, 
                    unit:arrIng[unitIndex],
                    ingredient:arrIng.slice(unitIndex +1).join(' ')
                };
```

Finally, thanks for Barmar to keep providing me with the new idea of how to fix this. Happy coding @Barmar, and thank you.

Comment: It would really help if you showed examples of `el` strings. Why would `arrCount[0]` be `0`? That would happen if the recipe said "0 tsp".

Comment: It's probably `arrCount[0] == ""`, not `== 0`. Since you're using loose equality, they compare equal.

Comment: That will happen if the ingredient begins with a space. `" foo".split(" ")` returns `["", "foo"]`